# ros c++ pause unpause gazebo

Tags: gazebo, c++, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to control the gazebo simulation by c++.
My core code is below:

```
        ros::ServiceClient pauseGazebo = n_.serviceClient<std_srvs::Empty>("/gazebo/pause_physics");
        std_srvs::Empty pauseSrv;
        pauseGazebo.call(pauseSrv);
        std::cout<<"enter q to continue"<<std::endl;
        char key;
        std::cin>>key;
        if('q' == key)
        {
            pauseGazebo.shutdown();
            ros::ServiceClient unpauseGazebo = n_.serviceClient<std_srvs::Empty>("/gazebo/unpause_physics");
            std_srvs::Empty unpauseSrv;
            pauseGazebo.call(unpauseSrv);
            std::cout<<"q is pushed"<<std::endl;
        }
```

The puase work well, after I enter q, the "q is pushed" output, but the gazebo is still in the state of pasue.
Can you provide some tip?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319774/ros-c++-pause-unpause-gazebo/) by [TouchDeeper](https://answers.ros.org/users/39695/touchdeeper/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2019-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have a typo in your code. The second service call should be

```
unpauseGazebo.call(unpauseSrv);
```

whereas you have

```
pauseGazebo.call(unpauseSrv);
```

which you have already shutdown.

A couple of more suggestions / information (as I have OCD)

You don't need to explicitly call shutdown as per [documentation](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1ServiceClient.html#ad0cee09b54fafe631486fb08772a0755). When the service client goes out of scope, it will be automatically shutdown.

Also, declaring everything on the top makes the code more readable, like this

```
    ros::ServiceClient pauseGazebo = n_.serviceClient<std_srvs::Empty>("/gazebo/pause_physics");
    ros::ServiceClient unpauseGazebo = n_.serviceClient<std_srvs::Empty>("/gazebo/unpause_physics");
    std_srvs::Empty pauseSrv;
    std_srvs::Empty unpauseSrv;
    char key;

    pauseGazebo.call(pauseSrv);

    std::cout<<"enter q to continue"<<std::endl;
    
    std::cin>>key;
    if('q' == key)
    {           
        unpauseGazebo.call(unpauseSrv);
        std::cout<<"q is pushed"<<std::endl;
    }
```

---

Originally posted by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) with karma: 849 on 2019-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TouchDeeper](https://answers.ros.org/users/39695/touchdeeper/) on 2019-03-28**:
Hi,@janindu
Thanks for your point. You are right. I‘m too careless.